# How to use jquery.validete on rendered form returned by ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a slight problem with usage of jquery validation plugin.

It works perfectly with static forms rendered during normal pageload.
The code I use for validation looks something likie this

```
$('#form_name).validate({ (...) and other stuff
```

The problem is when I use ajax request to create popup form with the same ID it won't work.

I couldn't find proper answer form this issue so I came here. I guess the *$().live* method could be usefull but I have no idea how to use it on no event like "click", "submit" etc..

Ow and to prevent other questions the page where new ajax form is loaded is located somwhere else than the page where the static form is rendered so there is no conflicts of two identical forms on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this problem before.  Newly added ajax content may need the triggers reinitialising.  There are several approaches you can take.  Below is just one of them.

put the javasciprt bind triggers inside a function and call it after the ajax request.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

 // when page has loaded do the binds 
 $(document).ready(function(){
   initBinds();
 });

 // This is your ajax request psuedo code
 function someAjaxRequest(){

    // 1) do some ajax request then 
    // 2) load the data 
    // 3) after this has been done then call initBinds() 
          function to re-init new data with bind triggers
 }

function initBinds()    {
   $('#someID').bind('click', function(){
     // blah blah
   })


   $('#someOtherID').bind('click', function(){
     // blah blah
   })

}
</spript>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said there are several solutions for this issue. I did almost what you say and it works fine. The difference is that I've  put all my validation code into defined function (in  this case *initBinds*) and call it twice: on document ready, and on ajax request so there was no neet to bind events like click or so. Thanks again for showing me right direction.

Comment: You can also change .bind into .live  (i think) which should change the triggers to always listen. You would need to read the documentation on the .live() as I cant remember 100% how it works.